# Override Hystrix properties when using Spring Cloud Netflix

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, hystrix

I am having a Spring Boot application that uses Netflix Hystrix via the Spring Cloud libraries, everything is working fine.

I want to override some basic properties for Hystrix, like `hystrix.threadpool.default.coreSize` and/or `hystrix.threadpool.default.maxQueueSize` for example. Unfortunately, I could not find some out of the box Spring Boot properties to do this so what would I need to do to set up these properties at application startup?

How are these properties set up in the spring-cloud-starter-hystrix module?

Comment: Have you tried adding those properties to the `application.properties`?

Comment: Spring Cloud bridges the spring environment and Archaius that Hystrix understands. Unfortunately "it does not work" isn't helpful and we can't diagnose your problem without more information from you.  What are your config files, dependencies and the spring boot autoconfig report?  Maybe a project that duplicates the problem.

Comment: I think there is something wrong with my configuration, since it is a legacy application integrated (but not fully) with Spring Boot. Could you please confirm that using the standard Hystrix properties in the Spring application.properties file should work? I did not see this fact in the documentantion.

Comment: I've fixed my configuration and putting those properties in the Spring application.properties file works. @M. Deinum  I can mark your answer as the correct one, just move it from the comment section.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just adding those properties to the `application.properties` file should work.

```
hystrix.threadpool.default.coreSize=
hystrix.threadpool.default.maxQueueSize=
```

Comment: is application.properties loaded by default by hystrix/archaius. Or all properties file are loaded? I didn't find related document about this...